# Is there a way to configure Spring Boot API to set connection timeout for incoming request?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss, wildfly, high-traffic

I've deployed my high traffic SpringBoot Application on Wildfly 10. The server architecture for this application is nginx (Angular Application) -> (reverse proxy) -> wildfly server. Since we get high traffic during the hours, the 8080 port (wildfly application port) stays at CLOSE_WAIT because nginx closes the connection after certain period of time.

I'm looking to configure the Spring Boot Application to close the connection if the request time is lets say > than 5 seconds.

Example:

```
@GetMapping("test1")
public ResponseEntity test1(){
    return ResponseEntity.ok("TESTED!");
}

@GetMapping("test2")
public ResponseEntity test2() throws InterruptedException{
    Thread.sleep(300000);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("TESTED!");
}
```

**For test2 Get HTTP method is there a way to configure spring boot application / Wildfly / centos to set connection timeout for incoming request?**

Answer (score 0):

You can try `server.connection-timeout=300000` in your `application.properties.`

From the official documentation:

> server.connection-timeout= # Time in milliseconds that connectors will wait for another HTTP request before closing the connection. When not set, the connector's container-specific default will be used. Use a value of -1 to indicate no (i.e. infinite) timeout.

Or you can try to use the `@Transactional` annotation and set an argument to it as that:

`@Transactional(timeout = 300000)`

Comment: It didn't work. ```server.connection-timeout``` is deprecated. I'm using Spring Boot 2.3.